# Make Python filtering function faster

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, filtering

I have created a function with which I filter an Excel file first by selecting a specific amount of occurrences of an address and then I want to filter by how many unique people use each address. The code I use works but it takes a long time. Is there a better way?

Here's what I'm using:

```py
def main():
    path = input('Enter path :')
    name = input('Enter file name :')
    file = path + '/' + name + '.xlsx'
    address_history = pd.read_excel(file)
    #print(address_history['address'].value_counts())
    counts = dict(address_history['address'].value_counts())
    times = int(input('Enter minimum amount of occurences :'))
    address_occurances = dict()
    for k, v in counts.items():
        if v > times:
            address_occurances[k] = v
    print('\n')
    address = pd.DataFrame(
        data=address_occurances.items(),
        columns=['address' , 'occurences'])
    num_of_users = list()
    num = int(input('Enter minimum amount of Users :'))
    for ad in address:
        if len(list(address_history[address_history['address']==ad]['Username'].unique())) >= num:
            num_of_users.append(ip)
    df_final = address[address['address'].isin(num_of_users)]
        
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
        display(df_final)
    return address_history
```

Comment: Can you clarify your filtering logic? Also please provide an example of your `address_history` data set.

Comment: Get rid of the for-loops you do not need them. There are more efficient ways to do this. For example, do not convert your value_counts to a dict and iterate just keep the frame and filter . . . `counts = address_history['address'].value_counts(); address_occurances = counts[counts > int(times)]`

Comment: @jfaccioni  The logic i try to fit in the dataset is that i want to find firstly how many times does a certain address appears on the dataset and then i want to find how many users used that address.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thank you very much for the help.I actually have bigger problem on the second stage of filtering where i need to find the users using the addresses that are filtered in the first place. The part with num_of_users where it has to loop through the address to find how many are used by a certain amount of users